# ora-00917 missing comma in insert statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO service VALUES ( '', '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & ListBox1.Text & "', '" & ListBox2.Text & "',  '" & ListBox3.Text & "', '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & ListBox6.Text & "', '" & ListBox5.Text & "', '" & ListBox4.Text & "', TO_DATE('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "', 'dd-MM-YYYY')"
```

missing comma help me please!!

Comment: Use Prepared Statements to avoid this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a closing parentheses after your `TO_DATE()` call, which is causing your code to think that you have an extra parameter in your INSERT statement :

```
... TO_DATE('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "', 'dd-MM-YYYY'))"
```

**Parameterization, Not Concatenation**

You really should be using parameters to avoid issues like this (in addition to the protection that they provide you against nastiness like SQL Injection. An example of what this might looks like can be seen below :

```
' Build your connection '
Using connection As New OracleConnection("{your-connection-string}")
     ' Build your query (using parameters) '
     Dim query = Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO service VALUES ('', @combo1, @list1, @list2, @list3, @combo2, @list6, @list5, @list4, @date)"

     ' Build a command to execute '
     Using command As New OracleCommand(query, connection)
         ' Open your connection '
         connection.Open()
         ' Add your parameters '
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo1",ComboBox1.Text)
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@list1",ListBox1.Text)
         ' More omitted for brevity '
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.ParseExact(DateTimePicker1.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy", Nothing))

         ' Execute your command '
         command.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End Using
End Using
```